# Subquery driving NULL values into outer query

Tags: mysql

I keep getting NULL rows in a nested query

Provided we have the following tables:

1. 'article' containing article information
2. 'bom' containing an m-n relation between article IDs, forming a bill of materials

Not every article is appearing in the 'bom' table - some will neither appear as parent nodes, nor as child nodes in any bill of materials.

I'm trying to get a list of articles and include a concatenated string containing the bill of materials, in case my article is a parent node.

Hence I'm trying this query structure in MySQL:

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.name,
(SELECT group_concat(
   bom.quantity, ' times ',
   a_child.partnumber, ' ',
   a_child.name)
   FROM
      bom
      left outer join article a_child on a_child.id = bom.child_article
   WHERE
      bom.parent_article = a.id
) myBOM
from article a
```

The query should also return plain articles which are not a parent of any bom or a part of any bom.

In case a parent article *does* have an associated bom, it should be outlined on the myBOM column. Otherwise the column should just be empty.

I am now getting some lines returning NULL in the outer query, while others work just fine - and I can't figure out what is driving some to work, others to fail.

How do I go about this ?

**Update**: some sample data:

Table `article`:

```
id   | name    | partnumber
-----+---------+------------
1    | desk    | P001
2    | leg     | P002
3    | board   | P003
```

Table **bom**:

```
id   | parent_article | child_article | quantity
-----+----------------+---------------+---------
1    | 1              | 2             | 4
2    | 1              | 3             | 1
```

Expected output:

```
id   | name       | myBOM
-----+------------+-------------------------------------
1    | table      | 4 times P002 leg, 1 times P003 board
2    | leg        |
3    | board      |
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @PM77-1 i just updated the question with some sample data.
Issue is: it works sometimes, and sometimes not. and I have no idea what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess tables should be swaped and group_concut wrap with IFNULL instruction... The following query returns required result

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.name,
(SELECT IFNULL(group_concat(
   bom.quantity, ' times ',
   a_child.partnumber, ' ',
   a_child.name), '')
   FROM
      article a_child
      left outer join bom on a_child.id = bom.child_article
   WHERE
      bom.parent_article = a.id
) myBOM
from article a
```

Comment: than you,  @dmitry-reutov ! I tried that, but doesn't help either.

Comment: I tried and got this result

1 desc 4 times 0002 leg,1 times 0003 board
2 leg NULL
3 board NULL

Something wrong in it?

Comment: @FabianK, i edited ny answer, query in it returns exactly the result you wish...please check

Comment: Thank you, @dmitry-reutov ! I've applied the INFULL statement. Yet still, it works on some occasions, on others it doesn't in my live data.

It's really odd, but it is that part which drives the issue because when I take that entire part out it works just fine.

I will update my question with some further deatils on the surrouding query - it's part of a bigger chunk.